# Laravel 5.2 Intervention Image 500 Server Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, intervention

When I upload big images (4.2 MB) Intervention Image is throwing 500 Error...

```
private function resizeImage($path, $imgName){
    $sizes = getimagesize($path.$imgName);
    if($sizes[0] > $sizes[1]){
        ImageManagerStatic::make($path.$imgName)->fit(920,474)->insert(public_path() . "/uploads/applications/watermark.png",'bottom-right', 30, 30)->save($path."1_".$imgName);
    }else{
        ImageManagerStatic::make($path.$imgName)->heighten(474)->insert(public_path() . "/uploads/applications/watermark.png",'bottom-right', 30, 30)->save($path."1_".$imgName);
    }
    ImageManagerStatic::make($path.$imgName)->fit(440,226)->save($path."2_".$imgName);
    File::delete($path.$imgName);
}
```

It works for smaller files. `upload_max_filesize=10M`. When I comment this function it works :/

Comment: is there a way to get a descriptive error message? i'm sure it throws up with more than saying 500 server error. Turn on errors and logging in php.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same issue and increasing `upload_max_filesize` were not enough.
I also increased `memory_limit to 256M` and restarted the server. Then images were working with Intervention.
[Above changes are in php.ini file]

You may want to change `upload_max_filesize` and `memory_limit` according to file capacity you are using.

Comment: I'm also getting same issue and increased all mentioned fields but still not working. Strange thing is it works for 10mb image but throwing error for 5mb image.

Comment: See the server error logs and apply fixes based on them.

Answer (score 8):

Today I got the same issue in Laravel 5.5 while using Intervention Package for resizing images exactly at below code:

```
Image::make($image_tmp)->save($image_path);
```

I don't have access to `php.ini` file in server and server will take time for update so **temporarily increased memory limit in function itself** in my  Controller file like below:

In ImagesController.php file :-

```
public function addImage(Request $request){

    // Temporarily increase memory limit to 256MB
    ini_set('memory_limit','256M');

    $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = rand(111,99999).'.'.$extension;
    $image_path = 'images/'.$fileName;
    $image_tmp = Input::file('image');
    Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(1182, 1506)->save($image_path);
}
```

Hope it will help someone in future!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with Laravel 5.1 and Intervention Image library.
In my case the issue came from the line Image::make($file) not the upload part.

I tried change the values of:

- upload_max_filesize from 2M to 32M
- post_max_size from 2M to 32M

Change nothing to the error I received.

So I increase :

- **memory_limit to 256M**

**It solved my problem**. 
My hypothesis is that even if my image was about 6Mo, the image library needed a lot of memory to use it.

Answer (score 4):

edit your php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M

post_max_size = 40M
```

Maybe your post_max_size is under 4MB. And then restart the server.

Comment: I think ImageManagerStatic has max file size 4MB. Where can I edit this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

I tried every solution but i forgot to write into my file use Image; and this works.