# Laravel intervention cannot process 4mb image

Tags: laravel, filesize, intervention

I use laravel intervention to create image with watermark, but i found laravel intervention cannot handle image more than 2mb, here is my code:

```
// open an image file
$img = Image::make('msg-1-fc-40.jpg')->encode('jpg', 75);

$img->fit(250, 250, function ($constraint) {
  $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

// finally we save the image as a new file
$img->save('test.jpg');
```

How can i process the image more than 2mb?

Comment: The package can't handle it or *your server* can't handle it?

Comment: @AndyHolmesi'm using localhost now, the code keep return "shamirac.dev is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500" when i using 4mb image to test

Comment: Sounds like a memory issue rather than the package tbh

Comment: There is an error logged in the log file because you have HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @AndyHolmes if there is the problem of memory, what should i do?

Comment: @Maraboc it only happen when i use 4mb image, when i use 1.5mb image, there is no problem.

Comment: Up it, @chengwei. In your PHP ini etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 Intervention Image 500 Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543732/laravel-5-2-intervention-image-500-server-error)

Comment: @AndyHolmes i tried, no luck, i increase it to 3000M, but still that same, original value is 128M

Comment: You upped everything that's in that other answer? Also 3000 is a bit steep, try 256

Comment: In case if you are using WAMP or something like that pay attention to what version of PHP you are using and edit `php.ini` accordingly.

Comment: @AndyHolmes i change accordingly, but still not working, maybe have to limit the image when upload

Comment: @Jackowski i'm using XAMPP, by the way, godaddy server also return 500 error

Answer (score 1):

Image operations tend to be quite memory exhausting because image handling libraries usually 'unpack' all the pixels to memory.

A JPEG file of 3MB can thus easily grow to 60MB in memory and that's when you've probably hit the memory limit allocated for PHP.

As far I remember, XAMP only allocates 128 MB RAM for PHP.

Check your **php.ini** and increase the memory limit, e.g.:
`memory_limit = 512MB`

Then restart the server.

But this is not a good approach, the best approach is to compress and resize any image before saving it to the server.