# \Image::make fails in production ( Laravel )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I am trying to upload images through Laravelbackpack. Everything work properly in localhost, but when I deploy it on Heroku it fails.

The line that is causing the server error is:
$image =\Image::make($value)->encode('jpg', 90);

Comment: what is the error showing on debugging, in the 500 server error

Comment: Server error, nothing more.

Comment: is your image size sometimes more than 2mb, then you can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543732/laravel-5-2-intervention-image-500-server-error/49550474#49550474

Comment: No, it is not. The fact that is failing on production but is working in local makes it more difficult to debug it.

Comment: it might be your extension not enabled. try to find phpfpm error log..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you're using [Intervention image](http://image.intervention.io/) library. It requires PHP-GD or Imagick PHP extension. You can use GD for example. Heroku doesn't install it as default, but you can easily do it by requiring it in your `composer.json` file:

```json
{
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
        "ext-gd": "*",
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

[Heroku PHP Support doc page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support)

Comment: Works like a charm. I am just surprised why I could not find anything about this step in laravel backpack docs since they were using this code as boilerplate.